# Method that adds edges to a graph until all nodes have the given degree

Tags: python, graph, complexity

[Exercise 2-3](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=SaV59o7K0GMC&pg=PA16) in *Think Complexity: Complexity Science and Computational Modeling* by Allen B. Downey asks us to implement a method for a class of *undirected* graphs:

> Write a method named `add_regular_edges` that starts with an edgeless graph and adds edges so that every vertex has the same degree. The **degree** of a node is the number of edges it is connected to.
>
> To create a [regular](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_graph) graph with degree 2, you would do something like this:
>
> ```
> vertices = [ ... list of vertices ...]
> g = Graph(vertices, [])
> g.add_regular_edges(2)
> ```
>
> It is not always possible to create a regular graph with a given degree, so you should figure out and document the preconditions for this method.

This was a little difficult for me as I am still getting comfortable with Python. Here was what my solution ended up looking like (heavily commented for myself and others):

```
def add_regular_edges(self, deg):

    #for every node in the graph
    for v in self:
        
        #set the degree tolerance to 1
        tol = 1
        
        #while the degree of current node is less than the given degree
        while self.degree(v) < deg:
            
            #traverse over every node
            for w in self:
                
                '''if the 2 nodes do not equal one another, the current degree (v) is less than the given degree,
                and the other node (w) is less than the current tolerance -> add the edge'''
                if v != w and (self.degree(v) < deg) and (self.degree(w) < tol):
                    self.add_edge(Edge(v,w))
                    
            #increase the tolerance in case we could not fill all nodes in the first pass
            tol += 1
            
            #if at any point the tolerance is more than the degree, then we cannot complete the graph with the given degree
            if tol > (deg+1):
                raise ValueError("The graph cannot be converted to the given degree")
```

However, I have a strong suspicion that this is not the most optimal way to go about this. One of my friends commented that I might be able to do this using lists and enumerating over them?

Comment: Where are the rest of functions coming from? Have you overridden the `__iter__` method?

Comment: @hjpotter92 Yes I have overridden `__iter__`, it's only so I can initalize the graph with a list of Vertices and Edges if I need to though. The class just inherits from `dict`, so it's a dictionary of dictionaries (cause each vertex `v` is a dictionary as well). The other functions (`degree()` and `add_edge()`) were defined by me and just do exactly what they sound like.

Comment: Is `Edge(v, w)` different from `Edge(w, v)`?

Comment: @hjpotter92 Nope they are the same - that’s not to say that `v` and `w` are the same though.